# Tidying time series data by country

Tags: r, time-series

I have time-series data organized by country and then my variable of interest. When I occasionally have two rows that align both in year and country code how do I get to add the variable of interest?

For example

```
CC  Year  IV 

2   2000  6
2   2001  8
2   2002  14
2   2003  8
2   2001  2
2   2002  5
```

and I want the data tidied like so

```
CC  Year  IV 

2   2000  6
2   2001  10
2   2002  19
2   2003  8
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this question. There seem to be 3 issues. 1) Which two rows align in both year and country code? Maybe you could highlight them or say which ones in the text. 2) I only see one input row, but you say you have two rows. 3) When you say you "want the data tidied like so" did the other entries get deleted or moved to a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, your data look something like this (I added a few records with an extra country code):

```
df <- tibble(CC = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
       Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2000),
       IV = c(6, 8, 14, 8, 2, 5, 3, 12, 7))
```

It sounds like you want to sum the variable in column `IV` by country and by year.
This will do it:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(CC, Year) %>%
  summarise(sum_IV = sum(IV))
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   CC [2]
     CC  Year sum_IV
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2  2000      6
2     2  2001     10
3     2  2002     19
4     2  2003      8
5     3  2000     10
6     3  2001     12
```